# Why the output of my program is the value of secret?

Tags: integer-overflow

```
#define INT_MAX 2147483647
#define INT_MIN (-INT_MAX-1)
int main()
{
    int secret = 0x12345678;
    int array[1] = {0};
    printf("%d",array[INT_MIN+1]);
```

}
The code run without stack protector.

the question is about integer overflow, but i dont understand why it work because the value of INT_MIN + 1 is -2147483647. and if i want to print the value of secret, I need to write: array[-1]

Comment: You are doing -INT_MAX-1+1. And what do you call "value of secret" ?

Comment: i mean 0x12345678

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, The printf returns 0 as it is an array of int, not the secret.
I think that there is an unpredictable behavior due to index outbound. You are declaring an array of 1 element but referring to an outbound index of the array. Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170740/c-negative-array-index) can help.

Comment: im sorry i didn't mention it before, but the code work without stack protector