# Int subtraction from a string

Tags: c++, string

Why doesn't the code below give an error that says the array is out of range?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" - 50;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"Hello, world"` is a string literal which decays to a pointer and then pointer arithmetic happens.

Comment: Because pointer/subscript arithmetic doesn't carry overhead of bounds checking.

Comment: C++ doesn't have any bounds checking. It's your responsibility as a programmer to make sure there's no out-of-bounds errors in your code.

Comment: Why then adding 50 to a string gives an error and not a garbage values?

Comment: Undefined behavior is, well, *undefined*. It can cause crashes, it can seemingly work, it can result in "garbage", or it can [summon nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: As a side-note (and some shameless self-promotion), [negative indexes are valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170740/c-negative-array-index/47170794#47170794) and can sometimes be useful.

Comment: *Why doesn't the code below give an error that says the array is out of range?*  Because C++ is not a nanny language, and expects the programmer to provide a valid program to the compiler.  If the programmer provides an invalid program to the compiler, hilarity and hijinks ensue.  Some lament that such a policy can incur an overabundance of <s>bugs</s> *job security*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't give an error because it's your job to make sure to honor array bounds. Like many other things this is impossible to always detect so it's left up to the user to not do it.

Compiler have gotten better at warning about it though:

```
<source>:4:36: warning: offset '-50' outside bounds of constant string [-Warray-bounds]
<source>:5:36: warning: array subscript 50 is outside array bounds of 'const char [14]' [-Warray-bounds]
```

Both under and overflow on a constant string get detected just fine by gcc and clang.

Answer (score 3):

> Why the code below does not give the error that array is out of range?

Because `"Hello, world!"` is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) of type `const char[14]`that **decays** to a pointer(`const char*`) due to **type decay**.

Thus effectively, you're subtracting `50` from that resulting(decayed) pointer. And when `operator<<` dereferences this pointer, it will lead to **undefined behavior**.

---

Note that undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But **never rely** on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash